# C# Acces First Recorset Item from ADODB

Tags: c#

I need some help accessing a *recorset*. It seems that `rs[0].Value` or `rs[0].ToString()` is not OK.

The error I got is:

> cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type recordset.

```cs
object nRecordsAffected = Type.Missing;
object oParams = Type.Missing;  


rs = cmd.Execute(out nRecordsAffected, ref oParams,(int)ADODB.ExecuteOptionEnum.adExecuteNoRecords);
rs.MoveFirst();
while (!rs.EOF)
{
    if (rs.EOF != true && rs.BOF != true) {
        ou = rs[0].ToString(); //here is the error
        ou = ou.Substring((ou.IndexOf(",") + 1), (ou.Length - (ou.IndexOf(",") + 1)));
        result = ou;
    }
    rs.MoveNext();
}
rs.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Errors occurs here `ou = rs[0].ToString();`

Comment: This code looks like old VBScript i'm sure there are better ways to perform queries

Comment: Why are you using ADODB in the first place, instead of .NET's ADO.NET? You're paying for a costly COM interop operation for *every* method and property call.

Comment: The doc page [Retrieve data using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) shows the correct and *safe* way to read data from databases, and even retrieve strongly-typed data. No need to call `ToString()`, you can call `GetString(0)` or `GetInt32(0)`.

Comment: BTW this query ends up discarding every result except the last one. Is that really what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Database access in .NET is performed through ADO.NET, not ADO. Using ADO means using COM interop and paying a performance penalty for every method and property access. It's far easier, faster and *safer* to use ADO.NET, an ORM like Entity Framework or a microORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

The page [Retrieve data using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) in the docs shows how easy it is to execute a query and retrieve the results. Adapted for what this question seems to be doing :

```
using (var connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand(someQuery,connection);
    connection.Open();
    using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var csv=reader.GetString(0);
                var parts=csv.Split(",");
                //Do something with the second part
                Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
    }
}
```

The `using` blocks ensure the connection and reader are closed even if there's an exception. Without them, they may remain open for a long time, leading to blocking or even deadlocks.

With Dapper, things are even easier. Assuming the query returns a single field :

```
using (var connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //Executes the query and returns the result either as raw values 
    //or strongly-typed objects
    var items=connection.Query<string>(someQuery,connection);
    foreach(var csv in items)
    {
        var parts=csv.Split(",");
        //Do something with the second part
        Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Using LINQ, this can be simplified further:

```
using (var connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //Combine querying and splitting
    var items=connection.Query<string>(someQuery,connection)
                        .Select(csv=>csv.Split(",")[1]);
    foreach(var vallue in items)
    {
        //Do something with that value
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Or, as a function that returns the values directly :

```
IEnumerable<string> SecondValues(string connectionString)
{
    using (var connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //Combine querying and splitting
        var items=connection.Query<string>(someQuery,connection)
                            .Select(csv=>csv.Split(",")[1]);
        return items;
    }
}
```